# From curl Upload file, I want to save response object to variable

Tags: gitlab

I was following this documentation : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#upload-a-file

I want to save this response to a variable :

```
    {
  "alt": "dk",
  "url": "/uploads/66dbcd21ec5d24ed6ea225176098d52b/dk.png",
  "full_path": "/namespace1/project1/uploads/66dbcd21ec5d24ed6ea225176098d52b/dk.png",
  "markdown": "![dk](/uploads/66dbcd21ec5d24ed6ea225176098d52b/dk.png)"
}
```

The above response is from this curl :

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
 --form "file=@dk.png" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/uploads"
```

I tried :

1. `$json=$(curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<my token>" --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" --form "file=@./ticket.json" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/uploads")`
2. json=`curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<my token>" --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" --form "file=@./ticket.json" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/uploads"`

Both method doesn't return the json object that i want to save.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work by storing the result to a file like this :

> curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${TOKEN}" --header
> "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" --form "file=@./ticket.json"
> "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/uploads" >> path.json